# Connecting Python to a Heroku PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am exploring various features of the Python language. I have created a Postgres db on Heroku, am am looking to connect to it. I have the host, database user, port and password settings. I am not looking to deploy to Heroku, just connect locally to this db. Where can I get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Heroku, but maybe [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 10):

From [Heroku Postgres doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python), with `psycopg2` :

> To use PostgreSQL as your database in Python applications you will
>   need to use the psycopg2 package.
>
> ```
> pip install psycopg2-binary
> ```
>
> And use this package to connect to DATABASE_URL in your code.
>
> ```
> import os
> import psycopg2
>
> DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
>
> conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
> ```